# Powershell script to download and name files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

So I've got a powershell script that goes out at certain times and downloads files from a site and saves it to our network.  It's really super simple but I have one issue I need fixed.  First, the code:

```
$client = new-object system.Net.Webclient
$client.DownloadFile("http://app1.co.madison.il.us/circuitclerk/dockets/63/489641.TXT","\\risokcdatp001\automated_data\PeopleInfo\DataFile\Traffic\IL\Madison\July_ $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd.TXT)")
$client.DownloadFile("http://app1.co.madison.il.us/circuitclerk/dockets/63/599256.TXT","\\risokcdatp001\automated_data\PeopleInfo\DataFile\Traffic\IL\Madison\August_ $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd.TXT)")
$client.DownloadFile("http://app1.co.madison.il.us/circuitclerk/dockets/63/429855.TXT","\\risokcdatp001\automated_data\PeopleInfo\DataFile\Traffic\IL\Madison\September_ $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd.TXT)")
```

You can see the site it goes to and then it deposits the files on our network.  The problem is that I need to name the files based on the date and time uploaded thats on the site.  See the following HTML code for this:

```
 <td width="65%" colspan="2">
      <div align="center"><font size="3"><a href="http://app1.co.madison.il.us/circuitclerk/dockets/63/489641.TXT" target="_blank"><b>MONTH OF JULY 2013</b></a></font></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div align="center"><font size="3"><b>July 05, 2013 (11:19 AM)</b></font></div>
    </td>
```

How do I get powersheel to get that value (July 05, 2013 (11:19 AM)) and use it in my file name like the following: July-UpdatedYYYYMMDD.txt?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the HTML source?

Comment: No, the source is controlled by the court.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must have the exact date/time shown on the page, you need to turn the solution around. Start by examining the index page (where your second excerpt came from), then work with that that to extract the URLs and timestamps, and download as you're doing but with the new file name.

Except...you can't [easily parse arbitrary HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Now, if you know that this HTML is pretty static in how it's formed, you can probably get away with it. But be prepared for things to break if the court changes their page even the tiniest bit.

If you don't need that level of precision, you can use the HTTP response headers that come along with the file when you download it. From this, you can get the `Last-Modified` date as reported by the server - the last date/time the file was modified on the server itself. This isn't necessarily the date you see in the web page, but rather when they put the file out there (so if there was a 2 hour lag from production to publishing, you might see that difference).

R is my RAMdisk I use for temp stuff. Fix your paths as needed.

```
$client = New-Object system.net.WebClient;
$client.DownloadFile("http://app1.co.madison.il.us/circuitclerk/dockets/63/489641.TXT","r:\tempfile.txt");
$updated = Get-Date $wc.ResponseHeaders["Last-Modified"] -Format "yyyyMMdd";
Rename-Item -Path "r:\tempfile.txt" -NewName "r:\July-Updated$updated.txt";
```

If you were using PowerShell 3.0, you could use `invoke-webrequest` to get the file into memory then write it directly out to disk with the appropriate name, as `invoke-webrequest` returns an object containing both the response data and headers which you can then handle as needed.

Still another option would be to contact the court and see if they have another, more machine-friendly, method of accessing the data. An RSS or XML feed, or some other kind of gateway that is meant for what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks, this looks perfect!  I'd love to have 3.0 but my work isn't too happy about using PS at all really.  I have lots of busy work and I'm trying to learn how to make the computer do most of it lol.  Thanks again, I'll fix my code tomorrow and let you know how it works when it runs.

Comment: "but my work isn't too happy about using PS at all" - That's really too bad, because PowerShell is the preferred way to administer Windows Server and most of the other MS software going forward. It's a standard part of Windows now and there's no compelling reason to *not* use it in place of older technologies.

Comment: I should have noted that I'm a data analyst just trying to make my job easier.  They won't give me any IT resources to make spiders to get the files I want so rather than downloading them manually each month, I just make powershell scripts to do it for me.  I would LOVE if the court were able to give us this through a feed of some type but they haven't been too keen on the idea.

Comment: If your employer actively discourages looking for better and more efficient ways of doing things, it's time to look for a new employer. And it bears repeating - PS is a **standard part of Windows now** so there should be almost no concerns about people using it.

Comment: Thanks alroc - I'm trying to work my way out as we speak (type).  I'm enhancing my skills and looking at other options.